# Spring data Mongodb - Encrypting a single field using convertor

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a collection which has several array of objects. In one of the sub-objects there is a field called secret which has to be stored in encrypted format, the field is of type String.

What is the best way of achieving?

I don't think writing a custom writer for the entire document is feasible.
How to write a String convertor that will be only applied for this single field?

Answer (score 0):

There are many answers to this questions and different approaches that depend on your actual requirements.

The first question that you want to ask is, whether MongoDB is a good place to store encrypted values at all or whether there is a better option that gives you features like rewrapping (re-encrypt), key rotation, audit logging, access control, key management, …

Another thing that comes into play is decryption: Every time you retrieve data from MongoDB, the secret is decrypted. Also, encrypting a lot of entries with the same key allows facilitates cryptanalysis so you need to ensure regular key rotation. Least, but not last, you're in charge of storing the crypto keys securely and making sure it's hard to get hold of these.

Having a dedicated data type makes it very convenient writing a with a signature of e.g. `Converter<Secret, String>` or `Converter<Secret, Binary>` as you get full control over serialization.

Alternatively, have a look at https://github.com/bolcom/spring-data-mongodb-encrypt or external crypto tools like HashiCorp Vault.